# Monitor assignment PHP extension

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to make an extension that monitors every assignment that is made in PHP.

I want to do some taint detection, I've seen the PHP taint project, but it would be nicer to have it as an extension for my project.

Additionally, where can I find API documentation and similar for Zend/PHP extensions, I haven't been able to find anything good :/

Comment: Unless it's for learning (it's an interesting enough field!) - would using classes with getters/setters not be an easier alternative?

Comment: Lets call it learning then ;) It would be easier, but code like $name = $_GET["name"]; would not be tracable then.

Comment: Source code is available here: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/taint - This shows as well how to use the API. You won't be able to build this with a sole extension, as you need to track every assignment I assume.

Comment: So it is completely impossible to track the assignments from an extension? If so, drop an answer and I'll look more into the taint project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://pecl.php.net/package/taint